# Postgres order by using value from a joined table

Tags: postgresql

I have a  table of conversations, and one of messages. I want to return a list of conversations ordered by their

```
select *
from "conversations"
         left outer join "messages" on "conversations"."sender_id" = "messages"."sender_id" and event = 'user'
order by (cast("messages"."parse_data" -> 'transcription' ->> 'confidence' as double precision)) nulls last fetch next 50 rows only
```

And here is the index created :

```
create index "messages_parse_data_transcription_index_bt"
    on messages using btree (sender_id, event, (cast("messages"."parse_data" -> 'transcription' ->> 'confidence' as double precision)) asc NULLS LAST );

analyse messages;
```

Unfortunately while it works on a large database (3GB, 7M lines on messages) it takes a very long time. Index creation is already very long (3m), and the query itself is also very very long (2M48)

```
Limit  (cost=523667.88..523673.63 rows=50 width=3052) (actual time=132421.177..142355.335 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=523667.88..560621.87 rows=321339 width=3052) (actual time=131738.458..141672.591 rows=50 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 1
        Workers Launched: 1
        ->  Sort  (cost=522667.87..523471.22 rows=321339 width=3052) (actual time=131626.455..131626.606 rows=48 loops=2)
              Sort Key: ((((messages.parse_data -> 'transcription'::text) ->> 'confidence'::text))::double precision)
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 125kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 125kB
              ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=369055.84..511993.22 rows=321339 width=3052) (actual time=101533.553..131406.086 rows=279394 loops=2)
                    Hash Cond: ((conversations.sender_id)::text = (messages.sender_id)::text)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on conversations  (cost=0.00..2634.32 rows=69832 width=33) (actual time=0.018..22.318 rows=59357 loops=2)
                    ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=281743.66..281743.66 rows=227615 width=3011) (actual time=90093.869..90093.870 rows=276748 loops=2)
                          Buckets: 2048  Batches: 512  Memory Usage: 2352kB
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on messages  (cost=0.00..281743.66 rows=227615 width=3011) (actual time=404.291..52209.756 rows=276748 loops=2)
                                Filter: ((event)::text = 'user'::text)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 3163558
Planning Time: 20.895 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 27
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 18.348 ms, Inlining 174.073 ms, Optimization 889.102 ms, Emission 424.619 ms, Total 1506.142 ms"
Execution Time: 142365.711 ms
```

How can I speed up my query execution ?

Comment: Do you really need to select every column from each table?

Comment: Is the left join really necessary?  Having that precludes some optimization possibilities.  In the unlikely event you would need to delve into the NULLs to get 50 rows, maybe you can live with the short set, or make up for them programmatically.